# Using the Android hardware side button

Tags: java, android, api, android-layout, android-ndk

I am working with a Motorola Droid. I can see there is a side button which launches the camera.

In my app, I use a button which when pressed, allows the user to talk - like in a walkie-talkie i.e it is a push-to-talk button.

How do I use the side button to work like this button? i.e use it as a push-to-talk button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity can override `onKeyDown()` and watch for `KEYCODE_CAMERA` `KeyEvents`:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA) {
      // do something

      return(true);
    }

    return(super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
  }
```